# 16.04 can't uninstall libreoffice 6

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice

Title says it all. I installed it via app grid or ubuntu software center, not sure which one. The software app does not function properly for me in xubuntu so, i decided to install libreoffice from alternatives.

However i realised afterwards that i ended up with 2 versions of the application.

Decided to remove all and reinstall, then i removed libre-office 5 successfully but not the 6. Problem is, version 6 doesn't show up in package lists and i'm not very experienced on the matter of package location and removal.

Here's the "dpkg --get-selections" list:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpkwn0c6fx60twb/installed.txt?dl=0

I don't know which one to remove to get rid of libreoffice 6.

I don't want to get my hands dirty digging up files and folders, i'm worried about leaving leftovers. So if someone knows what's going on please help me out.

Edit: There is no desktop file for libreoffice in /usr/share/applications.

```
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice %U


    Actions=Writer;Calc;Impress;Draw;Base;Math;

    [Desktop Action Writer]
    Name=Writer
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.writer

    [Desktop Action Calc]
    Name=Calc
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.calc

    [Desktop Action Impress]
    Name=Impress
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.impress

    [Desktop Action Draw]
    Name=Draw
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.draw

    [Desktop Action Base]
    Name=Base
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.base

    [Desktop Action Math]
    Name=Math
    Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice_libreoffice.desktop /snap/bin/libreoffice.math
```

Comment: What does `locate libreoffice` show?

Comment: @DKBose this is the output https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk1hh0c8jy9pb8u/locate.txt?dl=0  ---- and by the way it's still fully functional despite i removed almost everything i could find that is related to libreoffice. I'm going nuts, wasn't even a manual install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the LibreOffice 6.0 snap package (*libreoffice*). Snap packages do not appear in the results of `dpkg --get-selections` . To uninstall the LibreOffice 6.0 snap package, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```

Comment: Worked just fine thank you. Now i'm off to search about this snap thing. It seems to have earned it's name though !

Comment: @anonim The best way to learn about snap packages is to run the command: `man snap`

Comment: So what do you think ? Was is app grid that installed it or any chance ubuntu software center may have?

Comment: I searched and searched before answering this question to find out if Ubuntu App Grid supports snap packages, but I didn't find anything. Ubuntu Software Center does not list snap packages, but the Ubuntu Software app in 16.04 does list snap packages. The best way to install snap packages is from the terminal by running `snap info package-name` first to check if the snap package named package-name or whatever has any required installation options as many snap packages do.

Comment: Thank you very much for all help, much appreciated.  It appears then i installed it via Ubuntu Software. It, 95 percent of the time, does not load for me, nor does it function properly when it does launch.  I did indeed try installing via Software first but when it didn't function i just closed it.  Apparently it managed to install some stuff. And then when i used App Grid, i chose to blame it.

Comment: Try clicking the little orange notification icon next to **Updates** in the Ubuntu Software menu bar if there is any little orange icon and update Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Well i already tried every possible solution listed online, it just doesn't work for me no matter what. And with this new(for me) snap thing i'll better sail on familiar seas. Also no, there is no orange icon for me unfortunately. Thanks for your time, have a nice day and thank you again, very much.